# How can I use the certificate I bought using Indy?

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, indy

I'm using the last version of Delphi.

I bought an SSL certificate and I received 3 files: `intermediate.txt`, `root.txt`, `ssl certificate.txt`

I created a little web service and configured it like this:

```pascal
LIOHandleSSL := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(Self);  
    
LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.CertFile     := "ssl certificate.txt";
LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := "root.txt";
LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.KeyFile      := "intermediate.txt";
    
LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmServer;
LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
```

Then I start the server and I receive errors:

> could not load key, check password

> error: PEM routines no start line

If I remove the `KeyFile`, the program starts, but then when I try to connect with any client (I also tried PHP) I receive another error:

> error accepting connection with ssl, get_client_hello: no shared cipher

I don't know what do do. Can anybody help, please?

Comment: The `CertFile` and `KeyFile` need to be in PEM or PKCS12 format, and the `RootCertFile` needs to be in PEM format. It doesn't sound like yours are. `.txt` is not a usual file extension for those formats. PKCS12 is `.p12` or `.pfx`, and PEM is `.pem`. Also, if the files are password-protected, make sure you have an `OnGetPassword/Ex` event handler assigned to provide the password when prompted.

Comment: Hello remy thank you for helping me. I received those as txt. Is there a way to convert them to PEM? I tried just renaming the files but it does not work.

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing what format the files are actually in. Open them up in a text editor and look at the first couple of lines, what do they say?

Comment: It says this -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGbjCCBVagAwIBAgIQZpCkzhbeXlB7J3uK4AtpUjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB
lTELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G

Comment: That is PEM format

Comment: Ok so I renamed as pem but I have the same problems. Do you have any idea that could help me? I don't have any ideas left

Comment: Doesn't sound like `intermediate.txt` is a valid certificate key.  Maybe i contains other certificates or CAs instead? Did your provider give you any instructions with these files?

Comment: Just this, https://myssl.ssl247.it/kb/ssl-certificates/install and also another link where to download root and intermediate certificate

Comment: Based on those instructions, I don't think `intermediate.txt` is a key file, it sounds more like an intermediate CA certificate chain file. Don't you have a private key for your main certificate? I think you need to talk to your provider and ask how to use their certificates with OpenSSL. The instructions you linked to don't cover that, only popular web servers.

Comment: Ok i will try to write them, thank you

Comment: Hello, ok you were right. Private key was missing (and also the password). I have now added both. Now WS starts and using a web page I can use it correctly. For some reason when using php and curl I receive the error "error accepting connection with ssl, ssl routines : ssl3_read_bytes: tlsv1 alert unknown ca"

Comment: Also..considering now i have 4 files how am I supposed to set up indy? What file do I use? Private key, certificate and root? I don't need intermediate, do i?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I also tried to use version 0.9.8e downloaded from here https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/ and with that the error changed to SSL3_GET_RECORD: wrong version number

Comment: I don't know if the intermediate file is needed or not. The other 3 files should work. But 0.9.8e is an *extremely* old version of OpenSSL. Indy officially supports up to 1.0.2u, which you can get from https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries. Support for 1.1.x is [in progress](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299).

Comment: I tried the version you proposed. As before if I try to use php and curl I receive the error on the server: "error accepting connection with SSL, sslroutines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca"

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added the answer to my problem. I have one last thing to ask. Now everything is working using this: LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2] ; I thought this meant that only TLS 1.2 would be accepted. However it looks like it disabled SSL but TLS 1 and TLS 1.1 are still accepted. how can I disable those and allow just TLS 1.2 ?

Comment: Specifying `[sslvTLSv1_2]` should indeed enable only TLS 1.2 and not enable TLS 1.0 or 1.1 at all. If that is not working, then double-check the return values of Indy's `IsOpenSSL_TLSv1_0_Available()`, `IsOpenSSL_TLSv1_1_Available()`, and `IsOpenSSL_TLSv1_2_Available()` functions in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit after OpenSSL has been loaded into memory. If TLS 1.1 or 1.2 are not available, Indy will silently fallback to TLS 1.0.

Comment: This is very weird. All three functions return true but I have set this LIOHandleSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];

Comment: @RemyLebeau do you have any idea on how to solve that? thank you!

Comment: those functions returning true just means that OpenSSL supports those TLS versions, not that they are actually being used. If you set `SSLVersions` to only `sslvTLSv1_2` then Indy will use OpenSSL's `TLSv1_2_method()`/`TLSv1_2_server_method()`/`TLSv1_2_client_method()` functions, and their documentation states: "***A TLS/SSL connection established with these methods will only understand the TLSv1.2 protocol**. A client will send out TLSv1.2 client hello messages and will also indicate that it only understand TLSv1.2. A server will only understand TLSv1.2 client hello messages.*"

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was.

1. In the Indy configuration, property RootCertFile I needed to use the intermediate certificate, not the root.
2. regarding curl, I had to install curl certificate inside php

Everything works now.
Thank you!